# Custom x509CertificateValidator validation not being invoked in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, client-certificates

A WCF service uses certificate security with self-signed certs. From googling this, it seems that the default validator should fail, but the service is functional. I can't find anywhere that certificateValidationMode is set to change this default behavior, or recognize anything else that would change it, so I am confused.

I have configured a WCF service to use a custom x509CertificateValidator in order to validate the certs. However the Validate() method is not being called. My question is - why is the Validate method not being invoked?

I have not configured WCF services with certificate security before so it's possible I am missing something obvious. I suspect the problem is somewhere else in the code, but I don't know what exactly what else to look for.

Here is where I set the custom validator:

```
    viewerHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ViewerService));

    viewerHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
    viewerHost.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new CertValidator();

    viewerHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
        typeof(IViewerService),
        getBinding(true, true),
        @"net.tcp://localhost:8746/Viewer/");
    setCertificate(viewerHost);
    addThrottlingBehaviour(viewerHost);
    viewerHost.Open();
```

Here is the code for getBinding() in the above excerpt, with an attempt to set the credential type commented out (it stopped connections altogether without the Validate() method being invoked):

```
private static CustomBinding getBinding(bool useCompression, bool useSSL)
{
    BindingElementCollection elements = new BindingElementCollection();

/* I tried the following after reading CodeCaster's comment, which did not work:             
    SecurityBindingElement security = 
  SecurityBindingElement.CreateCertificateOverTransportBindingElement();*/

    // MessageEncoding
    BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement binaryMessageEncodingBE = new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement();
    if (useCompression)
    {
        GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement gZipMessageEncodingBE = new GZipMessageEncodingBindingElement(binaryMessageEncodingBE);
        elements.Add(gZipMessageEncodingBE);
    }
    else
    {
        elements.Add(binaryMessageEncodingBE);
    }

    if (useSSL)
    {
        SslStreamSecurityBindingElement sslStreamSecurityBE = new SslStreamSecurityBindingElement();
        sslStreamSecurityBE.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls11;    // Currently MD5 certs are in use. This will be changed when they are replaced with SHA256 ones.
        elements.Add(sslStreamSecurityBE);
    }

    // TcpTransportBindingElement
    TcpTransportBindingElement tcpTransportBE = new TcpTransportBindingElement();
    tcpTransportBE.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1048576;
    tcpTransportBE.ListenBacklog = 1000;
    tcpTransportBE.MaxPendingConnections = 1000;
    tcpTransportBE.MaxPendingAccepts = 1000;
    tcpTransportBE.ConnectionPoolSettings.MaxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint = 1000;
    elements.Add(tcpTransportBE);

    CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(elements);

    BindingContext context = new BindingContext(binding, new BindingParameterCollection());
    XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = binaryMessageEncodingBE.GetProperty<XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas>(context);
    quotas.MaxArrayLength = 1048576;
    quotas.MaxStringContentLength = 1048576;



    return binding;
}
```

setCertificate() implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets a server certificate for a service host
/// </summary>
/// <param name="serviceHost"></param>
private static void setCertificate(ServiceHost serviceHost)
{
    // A certificate has to be installed on the server. This certificate is used for SSL encryption
    serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
        "localhost");
    var test = serviceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate;
}
```

Comment: The default authentication for net.tcp is Windows auth, so it would seem your client cert is ignored.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster. How do I configure it to use certificate credentials? I will add what I tried to the answer..

Comment: For how to create a service that uses a custom certificate validator, you can refer to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-create-a-service-that-employs-a-custom-certificate-validator
and transmission security using certificate authentication requires that the server certificate and the client certificate trust each other. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication